# Generate R data-frame with close prices in wide format instead of log-returns using Tidyquant (R-Project)

Tags: programming, portfolio-optimization

I need to generate a wide-formatted data frame with close price (not log returns) from Tidyquant, using syntax that's similar to that listed below for wide-formatting log-returns:

```
log_ret_tidy <- price_data %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted,
               mutate_fun = periodReturn,
               period = 'daily',
               col_rename = 'ret',
               type = 'log')

log_ret_xts <- log_ret_tidy %>% spread(symbol, ret) %>%  tk_xts()
```

It may be just an R-command I need, which could probably be done with some wrangling, but I basically need something like the wide-formatted data frame **log_ret_xts** but with closing price, so I can export the data.

Comment: How is your `price_data` structured? Did you get it via `tq_get()` function. Then you can probably just do the following:                                                                                   `close_tidy <- price_data %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  select(date, close)` 
and `close_tidy_xts <- close_tidy %>% spread(symbol, close)`. See if it helps and whether it gives you the proper data format.

Comment: That worked! Thanks.